# Print out array user entered

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to printout the number the user entered, but i got an error. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int size=0,score=0;
    int [] a=new int[size];
    int len=a.length;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 to 5: ");
        size=input.nextInt();
    }
    while ((size<1) || (size>5));
    for (int i=1;i<=size;i++)
    {   
        do
        { 
            System.out.print("Enter your "+i+" score (1-100):");
            score=input.nextInt();
        }
        while((score<1) || (score>100));
    }
    for (int i=1;i<=size;i++)
        System.out.println(a[i]+ " ");
    }
}
```

Here's my output and the error:
Please enter a number between 1 to 5: 2
Enter your 1 score (1-100):54
Enter your 2 score (1-100):64
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Week08.BigArray2.main(BigArray2.java:27)

Comment: Your for loop format is wrong. Arrays in Java start at 0 and end at length-1, change the for loops to "for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)"

Comment: When you create the `a` array, `size` is 0, so the array is always 0 entries big. Hence it crashes when you try to save something into the array. Move the `a = new int[size]` to a line after you've read the size.

Comment: I understand the problem now. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

There are four mistakes in your code

1. array initialized with zero size
2. user input not stored in the array
3. iterating from index 1 but array starts with 0
4. Scanner not closed

   ```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int size = 0, score = 0;

   do {
       System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 to 5: ");
       size = input.nextInt();
   } while ((size < 1) || (size > 5));

   int[] a = new int[size]; //1

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       do {
           System.out.print("Enter your " + (i + 1) + " score (1-100):");
           score = input.nextInt();
           a[i] = score; //2
       } while ((score < 1) || (score > 100));
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //3
       System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

   input.close(); //4
   ```

output

```
Please enter a number between 1 to 5: 4
Enter your 1 score (1-100):99
Enter your 2 score (1-100):98
Enter your 3 score (1-100):97
Enter your 4 score (1-100):96
99 98 97 96
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues with you code:

1. Array declared with zero size. In java, size of array is declared at the time of initialization and it can altered later.
2. You never stored score into an array. Hence array was empty.
3. Always start loop index with zero in java while iterating array.

Here it is the modified working program:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayPrint {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = 0, score = 0;
        int[] a;

        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 to 5: ");
            size = input.nextInt();
        } while ((size < 1) || (size > 5));

        //Allocating space to array
        a = new int[size];
        int len = a.length;

        for (int i = 0; i <size; i++) {
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter your " + i + " score (1-100):");
                score = input.nextInt();
                a[i] = score;
            } while ((score < 1) || (score > 100));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
            System.out.println(a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Please enter a number between 1 to 5: 2
Enter your 0 score (1-100):22
Enter your 1 score (1-100):11
22 
11
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at your 4th line of code `int [] a=new int[size];`, size=0 at this time and you have initialized the integer array "a" with size 0 but you are trying to iterate array "a" at last with code `for (int i=1;i<=size;i++)
System.out.println(a[i]+ " ");
}` which is causing the array index out of bound exception.

Move below lines of code after first do while loop-:

```
int[] a = new int[size];
    int len = a.length;
```

And now correct your last for loop as below-:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        System.out.println(a[i] + " ");
}
```

Index of array starts at **0** and ends at **size-1**.